# The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method

Tags: flutter

I wanted to fix the map error in the code below. The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method.

The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:maharlika_mobile/models/places/province.dart';

import 'package:maharlika_mobile/models/places/regions.dart';
import 'package:maharlika_mobile/views/sign_up/bloc/province_cubit.dart';


class TestProvince extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestProvince({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestProvince> createState() => _TestProvinceState();
}

class _TestProvinceState extends State<TestProvince> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    context.read<ProvinceCubit>().getProvinceFromApi(Region());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ProvinceCubit, Province>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, Province state) {
        if (state.provinceCode != null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: context.read<ProvinceCubit>().getProvinceFromApi(Region()).map(
                  (Province e) {
                    //region 1 ()
                    return ProvinceItem(province: e);
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}

class ProvinceItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProvinceItem({Key? key, required this.province}) : super(key: key);
  final Province province;
  @override
  State<ProvinceItem> createState() => _ProvinceItemState();
}

class _ProvinceItemState extends State<ProvinceItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Text(
        widget.province.provinceName!,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class ProvinceCubit extends Cubit<Province> {
  ProvinceCubit() : super(Province());

  late List<Province> _provinces = [];

  Future<List<Province>> getProvinceFromApi(Region region) async {
    _provinces = await getIt.get<PublicApiHandler>().getProvinces(regionCode: region.regionCode!);

    emit(_provinces.first);

    return _provinces;
  }

  void changeProvince({required Province province}) {
    emit(province);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your `getProvinceFromApi` returns a Future. To fix your issue you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the function you call is Future, you need to "await" it's callback if you want to receive data from it.